# Implement a Execution Log in Java

Tags: java, executable-jar, swingworker

Coming from a WPF world, I am having a hard time implementing some basic stuff in Java.
I need to execute a *.JAR file from another java GUI application. This JAR file takes minutes to finish, and I want the GUI not to freeze.

So, my initial solution would be: create a SwingWorker class to call a command line in background.

My main concerns are:

1. I need to get the console output from the *.JAR file and show it in the GUI. Is it possible to update the GUI from a background thread?
2. Is it possible to cancel the thread from a user input?
3. How do I get notified that the thread is finished?
4. Is my solution a good one?

Comment: All of your questions have already been asked and answered here, except the last one, which is opinion based. Try to show more effort.

Comment: Googling for your question 1, I get this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html . Is that not sufficient?